# How to revert from "keep the local version currently installed" while Grub upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

While doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` I was asked if to keep current version of grub config and have answered "yes". Now my system has no network.

Message was "A new version of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified"

Is it possible in current situation to "install the package maintainer's version"? How can I reach "package maintainer's version" if I have selected to keep mine?

Comment: Possibly useful? [How can I install/view the grub file that a recent upgrade was providing but I accidentally ignored?](//askubuntu.com/a/799220)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the smartest idea but backup the `grub` configuration and try running `dpkg-reconfigure <package_name>` (wasn't sure if it's called grub or grub2).